# How to create object name in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var eachProduct = 
{
    "name": name,
    "id": id,
    "category":category,
    "price":price
};
```

Answer:

```
eachProduct[0].name
```

But i need Answer this type

```
eachProduct["First"].name
```

How to create object name ["First"]

Comment: var eachProduct =[{First: { "name": name, "id": id, "category":category, "price":price }}];

Comment: and the access to the node name is like this: eachProduct.First.name

Comment: Each product is an object here not an array

Comment: `eachProduct[0]` will return undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var product = {
  "name": "Name",
  "id": "ID",
  "category": "Cat",
  "price": "10"
};
var newObj = {};

newObj["First"] = product;

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: @Thamotharan No problem ! Does it totally answer your question ? If it is the case dont forget to mark it as the answer. If it is not, please update your question to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Or create your object like this format

```
var eachProduct = 
{
    'First': {
       'name': name,
       'id': id,
       'category':category,
       'price':price
    }
};
```

No need to declare a new object.
I preferred to use single quote in my JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var eachProduct = [
           {
               First: {'name': name,
                        'id': id,
                        'category':category,
                        'price':price
                      }

            },
           {
                   First: {'name': name,
                        'id': id,
                        'category':category,
                        'price':price
                      }
           }
  ]
```

{
    "name": name,
    "id": id,
    "category":category,
    "price":price
};